# IOS - angle between ipad and pitch-roll-layer

Tags: ios, ipad, angle, pitch

i used core motion in IOS to calculate the angle between ipad and pitch-roll-layer, but i didnt know how i can calculate the angle between ipad-layer and pitch-roll-layer from yaw-, pitch- and roll-value. In the below image, i want to calculate the α - angle. Please help me!
thx

is this below calculation correct?

α = 90 - atan2(sqrt(pow(acceleration.x,2)+pow(acceleration. y,2)),acceleration.z)

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/443/bild1nwcmm.png/

PS: the red line is my ipad-layer

Answer (score 0):

Not clear on the task. From CoreMotion you can obtain the current device attitude (CMMotionManager.deviceMotion.attitude) and then use that as a reference point (zero) so that you get delta angles for roll, pitch, and yaw (CMAttitude multiplyByInverseOfAttitude:).

```
@interface OrientationTracker : NSObject {
    CMMotionManager* motionManger;
    CMAttitude* referenceAttitude;
}

- (void)markZeroReference
{
    CMDeviceMotion* deviceMotion = self.motionManager.deviceMotion;
    self.referenceAttitude = [deviceMotion.attitude];
}

- (CMAttitude*)currentOrientation {
    return [self.motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude multiplyByInverseOfAttitude:self.referenceAttitude];
}
```

Comment: thx for your answer but what i need is how the α - angle (pls see this image http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/443/bild1nwcmm.png/) is calculated